# AngularJS Expression Concatenating Instead of Adding

Tags: angularjs

I have the following 2 expressions in my HTML (as the param for a controller function called within the ngClick directive), where I am trying to implement simple paging functionality:

`{{ (currentPage|number)+(1|number) }}` - This concatenates the two values together as if they were a string.

`{{ (currentPage|number)-(1|number) }}` - This calculates the correct and expected numeric result.

Any idea what the problem is here?  I have tried various ways to add a literal and AngularJS value together to no avail.  I am using version 1.2.0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since `+` is an addition and concatenation operator the concatenation is taking precedence whereas `-` is only subtraction. Try using `parseInt()` wherever you calculate the number value or within the expression.

Comment: This has worked a treat - thank you!

Comment: I submitted it as an answer to close off this question.

Comment: try to resolve from the controller an expose through the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `+` is an addition and concatenation operator the concatenation is taking precedence whereas `-` is only subtraction. Try using `parseInt()` wherever you calculate the number value or within the expression.

*submitted as it worked*

Answer (score 3):

In some extreme cases like mine, where none of the above solutions work, there is one saviour solution : subtract 0 and then perform the addition.

So your addition expression

`{{ (currentPage|number)+(1|number) }}`

could be re-written as

`{{ (currentPage|number) - 0 +(1|number) }}`

To further explain, the expression is forcibly made to appear as a number through the subtraction of 0.

Answer (score 1):

I tried parseFloat() but for some reason that didn't work. But since using the - will default to a math operation, instead of adding (+) I subtracted a negative.

```
    $scope.add = function() {$scope.counter += $scope.amount;} // doesn't work

    $scope.add = function() {$scope.counter -= -$scope.amount;} // works perfectly.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just Do like this :

```
{{ (currentPage|number)-(-1|number) }} instead of {{ (currentPage|number)+(1|number) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3anumber), the number filter returns a string. The `+` operator is the concatenation operation in String.

You have to parse the string into number by yourself.

Something like this:

```
.filter('toNumber', function() {
    return function(n) {
        return new Number(n);
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

{{" - " + (priceInfo.adjustment_base_price2)}}

make sure expression is inside the (brackets)